# The method setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType) is undefined for the type UrlImageView

Tags: java, android, video, android-intent

I'm getting an eclipse error stating "The method setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType) is undefined for the type UrlImageView"

### SOURCE:

```
    UrlImageView thumb = (UrlImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.userVideoThumbImageView);
    thumb.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

How is it possible to stretch the image simialer to setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY) on a UrlImageView?